# Permissions for users to send alerts to multiple users

Tags: permissions, alert

We have a number of subsites (off a main site) which are project based.  The project managers would like the ability to create alerts for their teams on specific items, such as Team Discussion and document lists, etc.

The PMs are not Site Administrators (nor should they need to be) but, by the same token, they can't set alerts which are sent to multiple users.

Does anyone know which permissions are needed to achieve this in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually create a custom permission level that includes the Manage Alerts permission and then grant that to the individuals you want.

Go into **Site Actions** > **Site Permission** and select **Permission Levels** from the **Manage** group on the ribbon.  Click **Add Permission Level** and under **Site Permissions** select **Manage Alerts** and give the new Permission Level a name and save it.  You can now grant that permission to existing or new users without giving them full access to the list or site.

Let me know if you need greater detail or have any follow-up questions.

Comment: I've granted Manage Alerts to the various PMs, but when they try to create an alert, they don't get the "send to" option, although I see it myself..

Comment: I just granted a user the Manage Alerts permission, logged in as them, navigated to a list, clicked Alert Me from the ribbon, and was able to create an alert for others on the site (i.e. added those user accounts to the "Send Alerts to" box.  Where are you trying to create these alerts?

Comment: HI Rob, turns out that one of the other PMs had no trouble configuring a multi-user alert.  We think it's a cached session or something for this one particular PM.  So problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The user needs Manage Alerts permission, which by default is only the Site Owner.

Comment: The Pms have Full Control permissions which includes Manage Alerts.. I'm lost as to why when they go to create alerts, they only get single user mode options.

Comment: I'm not sure what single user mode option is. Can multiple users be entered in the "Send Alerts To" box separated by semi-colons?

Comment: Yup, they can - it turns out that the PM testing her permissions must have had some sort of caching issue.  One of the other PMs was able to create a multi-user alert with no problems (same permissions as the other user).  Thanks for your help!